# TypeError: jsonFeatures.map is not a function using fuse-search in leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Trying to implement the fuse-search functionality in a leaflet map, however I am getting a TypeError: jsonFeatures.map is not a function.  Here is my javascript part of the code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl:false, maxZoom:35
        }).fitBounds([[33.0505857631,-97.0891295315],[46.4513087069,-74.8430449085]]);
        var hash = new L.Hash(map);
        var additional_attrib = 'created w. <a href="https://github.com/geolicious/qgis2leaf" target ="_blank">qgis2leaf</a> by <a href="http://www.geolicious.de" target ="_blank">Geolicious</a> & contributors<br>';
        var feature_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
        var raster_group = new L.LayerGroup([]);
        var basemap_0 = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            subdomains: ["otile1", "otile2", "otile3", "otile4"],
            attribution: 'Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png">. Map data (c) <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, CC-BY-SA.'
        }); basemap_0.addTo(map);   
        var layerOrder=new Array();
        function pop_mvpdataset(feature, layer) {                   
            var popupContent = '<table><tr><th scope="row">Company:</th><td>'+ Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Company'])) + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Business Line:</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['BusinessDescription']))+ '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">City:</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['City'])) + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">State:</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['State'])) + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">County:</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['County'])) + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Phone:</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Phone'])) + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Website</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Website'])) + '</td></tr></table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        }
        var exp_mvpdatasetJSON = new L.geoJson(exp_mvpdataset,{
            onEachFeature: pop_mvpdataset,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {
                    icon: L.icon({
                        iconUrl: feature.properties.icon_exp,
                        iconSize:     [50, 45], // size of the icon change this to scale your icon (first coordinate is x, second y from the upper left corner of the icon)
                        iconAnchor:   [12, 12], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location (first coordinate is x, second y from the upper left corner of the icon)
                        popupAnchor:  [0, -14] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor (first coordinate is x, second y from the upper left corner of the icon)
                    })
                })
            }}
        );
        var cluster_groupmvpdatasetJSON= new L.MarkerClusterGroup({showCoverageOnHover: false});
        cluster_groupmvpdatasetJSON.addLayer(exp_mvpdatasetJSON);
        //add comment sign to hide this layer on the map in the initial view.
        cluster_groupmvpdatasetJSON.addTo(map);

        feature_group.addTo(map);
        var title = new L.Control();
        title.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
            this.update();
            return this._div;
        };
        title.update = function () {
            this._div.innerHTML = 'Search using NAICS or SIC Code'
        };
        title.addTo(map);
        var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.OSMGeocoder({
            collapsed: false,
            position: 'topleft',
            text: 'Location Search!',
        });
        osmGeocoder.addTo(map);
    // Adding FuseSearch Control
    var searchCtrl = L.control.fuseSearch({collapsed: false})
    searchCtrl.indexFeatures(cluster_groupmvpdatasetJSON, ['Company', 'NAICS1', 'PrimarySIC']);
    feature.layer = cluster_groupmvpdatasetJSON;
    searchCtrl.addTo(map);

    // Allow switch between satellite and Hybrid Maps
    var mapquestOAM = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg", {
      maxZoom: 35,
      subdomains: ["oatile1", "oatile2", "oatile3", "oatile4"],
      attribution: 'Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" target="_blank">MapQuest</a>. Portions Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech and U.S. Depart. of Agriculture, Farm Service Agency'
    });
    var mapquestHYB = L.layerGroup([L.tileLayer("http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg", {
      maxZoom: 35,
      subdomains: ["oatile1", "oatile2", "oatile3", "oatile4"]
    }), L.tileLayer("http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/hyb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      maxZoom: 35,
      subdomains: ["oatile1", "oatile2", "oatile3", "oatile4"],
      attribution: 'Labels courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png">. Map data (c) <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, CC-BY-SA. Portions Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech and U.S. Depart. of Agriculture, Farm Service Agency'
    })]);
        var baseMaps = {
            'Street Map': basemap_0,
            'Aerial Imagery': mapquestOAM,
            'Imagery with Streets': mapquestHYB
        };
            L.control.layers(baseMaps,{"Manufacturing Companies": cluster_groupmvpdatasetJSON},{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);
            L.control.scale({options: {position: 'bottomleft',maxWidth: 100,metric: true,imperial: false,updateWhenIdle: false}}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things to say.

1/ You are providing to .indexFeatures() cluster_groupmvpdatasetJSON, which is a Leaflet layer. indexFeatures() expects a FeatureCollection, so you should pass in exp_mvpdatasetJSON instead.

2/ Assigning feature.layer should be done for every single feature, you need to do it in the pointToLayer function which is used as a parameter to L.geoJson() : create the marker, assign it to feature.layer, then return the marker.

3/ The plugin may not work properly with cluster groups, it hasn't been tested - this is on my list though ...

So you could change your code along these lines :

```
var exp_mvpdatasetJSON = new L.geoJson(exp_mvpdataset,{
    onEachFeature: pop_mvpdataset,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: feature.properties.icon_exp,
                iconSize:     [50, 45], 
                iconAnchor:   [12, 12], 
                popupAnchor:  [0, -14] 
            })
        });
        feature.layer = marker;
        return marker;
    }}
);
```

Hope this helps,
Antoine.

Comment: Antoine, the information is useful. However, I am not sure how to implement the feature.layer in the pointToLayer function. Any pointers to an example on the same?

Comment: See the code suggestion above.

Comment: I have changed my code according to your suggestions. However I am getting two errors i.e. unreachable code after return statement and jsonFeatures.map is not a function. Here is my current code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jonahke/sn9wp41b/ PS I am learning JavaScript

Comment: qgis2leaf is no longer being developed. Try qgis2web instead.

Comment: @Tom Will try the plugin